# How can I call functions in a list, catching exceptions and repeating a function if necessary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get user input on a number of questions that all have the same criteria (asking the user to rate something from 1 to 10).

I have each question as a function, and I call them in order of their position in the list with a for loop. Inside the for loop, I have a while loop checking them all for exceptions. However, Python is running all of the functions before checking for exceptions. I want it to run the first function, check for errors, and then run the second function. How can I implement this?

Here is my code :

```
interest_list = []
function_list = [cheese(), wine(), beer(), spirits(), \
              coffee(), chocolate()]
for afunc in function_list :
    loop_check = None
    while loop_check == None :
        try :
            if int(afunc) <= 5 and int(afunc) >= -5 :
                interest_list.append(afunc)
            else :
                raise RangeQuestionsError

        except (ValueError, RangeQuestionsError) :
            print(afunc, " is not a valid choice. Try again.", sep="")
            loop_check = None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling function while initializing the list that's not right try the following code

```
interest_list = []
function_list = [cheese, wine, beer, spirits, \
              coffee, chocolate]
for afunc in function_list :
    loop_check = None
    while loop_check == None :
        try :
            if int(afunc()) <= 5 and int(afunc()) >= -5 :
                interest_list.append(afunc)
            else :
                raise RangeQuestionsError

        except (ValueError, RangeQuestionsError) :
            print(afunc, " is not a valid choice. Try again.", sep="")
            loop_check = None
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take list as list of string and then use `eval` function to evalute it.

**Remember you'll have to define functions as well.**

```
interest_list = []
function_list = ['cheese()', 'wine()', 'beer()', 'spirits()', 'coffee()', 'chocolate()']

for func in function_list :
    afunc = eval(func)
    loop_check = None
    while loop_check == None :
        try :
            if int(afunc) <= 5 and int(afunc) >= -5 :
                interest_list.append(afunc)
            else :
        raise RangeQuestionsError
    except (ValueError, RangeQuestionsError) :
        print(afunc, " is not a valid choice. Try again.", sep="")
        loop_check = None
```